# MasterUserSecret field missing in describe-db-instances API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I have created the database with `ManageMasterUserPassword=True`. But I couldn't get the Secret Arn from the `describe-db-instances` command.

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-1 --query DBInstances[*].[MasterUsername,MasterUserSecret]
[
    [
        "postgres",
        null
    ]
]
```

I have created the database even from console,
[image]

Still I am facing the same error.
But I can clearly see the database ARN in SecretsManager and Secrets ARN in database.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have more recent awscli, the support for this feature was added in 2.9.10:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst

```
2.9.10
...
* api-change:``rds``: Add support for managing master user password in AWS Secrets Manager for the DBInstance and DBCluster.
...
```

With this, the output (only when the feature is enabled on the db instance) will contain:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-1 --region=us-east-1

...
"MasterUserSecret": {
                "SecretArn": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:776665554444:secret:rds!db-88888888-82e1-4a59-8c35-888888888888-SyXcpL",
                "SecretStatus": "active",
                "KmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:888888888888:key/88888888-c6c4-43da-a4a4-888888888888"
            },
```

You can get the actual values with (for example):

```
$ secret_arn=$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-1 --region=us-east-1 --query DBInstances[*].[MasterUserSecret.SecretArn] --output text)
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ${secret_arn} --region us-east-1 --query SecretString --output text
{"username":"admin","password":"SVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxY7gwkD"}
```

Comment: mine is 2.8.3.. But is it something linked with botocore module? I have upgraded boto3 module with pip install --upgrade. wont it help here?

Comment: you need [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)